# pivot table filter AND show items no data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel PivotTable and I don't understand when I filter and select to show items with no data that the field headings are inconsistently shown.

The 1st pic is the normal Pivot Table.

The 2nd shows a filter of "does Not equal" = TN

The 3rd pic shows that when "show items with no data" is selected for the 'Participating' column that TN is removed from the 0's child field but for the 1 it is left in with only the values removed.

I assume this is because with 1 field having only values for TN it would not be shown at all if not for the "show items with no data" option.

Is a way known to show the TN heading for both parent values?

[image: Click here for the image.]

Comment: I've tried replicating your steps, and setting the Participating option to 'show items with no data' did not override the filter of excluding "TN" in stamped.

Comment: Hmmm been looking at this the past week and a half.
Just tried again and I get the sane behavior.
Will try again from scratch to see if it is the same

It is just so strange that for a Participating value of 0, filtering to excluding TN from Stamped removes TN AND TN's data values but for Participating value of 1 the TN heading remains but TN's data values are gone.